Does understanding the concept of consent require a better/deeper understanding of the concept of wants/desires?
I’m currently thinking that the central question of sexual ethics is about what “consent” is, and I know there are other theorists analyzing that question.
I currently feel like it would be easy to get lost in details and not develop a fundamental theory if you focus too much on external scenarios and actions like, what did they say, what was the facial expression, or something. The underlying question is what the “structure” of the concept of “wanting” is. I am currently thinking that whenever we say “there has to be consent”, and then add, “real consent - the following scenarios are examples of specious or false consent: …”, we are asking a very simple question of what the difference between “authentically wanting” something vs. “inauthentically wanting” is. Focusing on this helps separate the inherent theoretical question of what it means for a person to want to do something versus the practical aspects of how that is communicated or determined in a context.
So the real question is an analysis of the ways in which someone can “want” something. Does understanding the concept of consent require a better/deeper understanding of the concept of wants/desires?

I recommend reading some comprehensive article such as https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/decision-capacity/ and then ask a more focused question on details here if need be.

@KristianBerry As the question was ultimately closed with a unaninimous vote of Needs more Focus, I think you're instincts were vindicated.

The problem with this question — and frankly, with current consent laws and societal attitudes in general — is that it takes what is obviously an interpersonal communication issue and tries to resolve it in terms of myopic, selfish individualism. I mean, the way to determine consent is to ask and listen to what the other says — d'oh! — but we have somehow become fixated on making objective/subjective assessments based on the other's apparent attitudes or behavior.
If someone says no they mean no, and there is no consent. If someone says yes (without compulsion) they mean yes, and there is consent. If they are conflicted and later regret saying yes, that is unfortunate. But we all have things we regret… We don't have to worry about authenticity; we only have to worry about being sensitive to what the other expresses.
Everyone carefully avoids talking about the gender bias inherent in this concept. The idea of consent arose in response to a traditional masculinist perception that women think emotionally, not rationally, and that it is up to men to decide what women want and convince or coerce them into accepting it. This creates all the stereotypically 'male' pursuit behaviors: assessing a woman's demeanor or clothing to see if she's 'receptive' or 'easy'; using stimulation (gifts, compliments, physical contact, intoxicants) instead of communication; stubborn pressure tactics intended to change a woman's mind; discounting women's statements as superficial or meaningless. But if we give up the idea that women are emotional creatures that men need to take care of and see women as intellectual equals with their own desires, confusions, and issues, then the issue of consent becomes a non-topic.

Part of the gender bias is that some people can get pregnant and others can't. Gambling is more appealing when it's someone else's money.

@KristianBerry: I expect there are overly-aggressive people in every human relationship. The general problem is that someone gets so fixated on their desires that they see another person as merely a vector for fulfilling those desires, and develop a sense of righteous entitlement about it. That 'entitled use' attitude has been baked into the idea of the feminine. No doubt it extends into LGBTQ relationships as well.

@ScottRowe: The number of children who have been born without male participation is either one or zero (depending on your religious inclinations), so it isn't fair to think of pregnancy as a 'woman' issue. If we had rigorous laws making men responsible for their genetic offspring (e.g., obligatory genetic testing, and child support costs that properly reflect the loss of time and opportunity women face), then I think men would be a whole level more respectful.

It would be great if men had to equally share the discomfort, risks and pain of pregnancy also. Surprisingly few men have died in childbirth.

You're a BAD BOY @ScottRowe. How DARE you talk factually in an ideologically charged context¿? Now stand in the corner for the rest of the period er... hour

Yeah, the problem isn't that it's difficult for the individual to figure out whether they are in the mood for something, the problem is that this is a subjective feeling, that is subject to change. And that consent requires it to be present during at least the entire process. So the fundamental problem isn't with subconscious desires, but with how the law addresses that. And while "no means no" and "(only) yes means yes" are obvious starters the idea of having that be a "pass" to proceed is inherently problematic as no amount of yeses override one even minor feeling of being uncomfortable

Though legally you're in a dilemma on the one hand the subjective feeling might be strong, while the objective expression might be weak, people might not readily be accustomed to subjective personal signals, the law requires testable evidence and is meant to rule in dubio pro reo. While on the other hand ignoring consent, especially in a domain which is so physically and emotionally close to the self, can be a traumatic experience of existential dread and mortal fear. So that's not a minor offense and just because certain body parts weren't in certain regions don't mean it's less severe.

Now with regards to gender bias, well it's usually a situation with a high degree of vulnerability and no witnesses, so even if "no's" and lack of consent were articulated, received and just ignored, you'd have to somehow proof that as the burden of proof is with the accuser or in that case the victim. And in a physical 1on1 with no gear or anything males are on average stronger, so in general this situation is more dangerous for the weaker part (usually women), which can be used to coerce even without bruises to show for especially as freezing is unfortunately also a natural reaction.

Though with regards to the game people play before it. Have you thought about that this is also a form of communication? That at least some of that isn't a set of challenges, but rather testing the waters as to how comfortable and vulnerable people can be around each other, what they are up to and whatnot and that a straight up yes answer requires experience of what is to come and that some just make them for the first time. So rather than taking things for granted and expected a yes, one might need to be more perceptive to actions and reactions.

Also for something more lighthearted about the answer. I guess you meant "duh" (obvious) rather than "d'oh" (which is afaik what Homer says as a mixture of "damn" and "no") :)

@haxor789: actually, I meant "D'oh", which I see as Homer chocking down the last syllable in order to avoid saying 'Damn' (because Homer's basically a decent guy who doesn't want to swear in front of the kids). I intended to convey sardonic shock at the horrible suggestion one might ask and listen.

@TedWrigley Mea culpa yeah that could also make sense :)
